# Determine the boundedness and monotonicity of the sequence with $a_n$ for $\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

$$\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+3}$$

Can I separate each part before and after subtraction and determine their montonicity? How does that relate to the combination?

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2n}$$

$$b_n = \frac{1}{2n+3}$$

both individually should be bounded and monotonic but is there a theorem such that subtracting two bounded and monotonic sequences means the difference will also be bounded and be monotonic?

Answer (score 1):

To show that it's monotone decreasing, simply use induction and the fact that $a_n-b_n = \frac{3}{2n(2n+3)}$ and induction. It's trivial to show that it is bounded since $a_n-b_n >0\;\forall n.$ By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, it has a limit.

Comment: Note the OP has already defined $a_n = \frac{1}{2n}$. Since you haven't given your own redefinition of it (note also I don't recommend this but, instead, you should usually choose your own separate variables; if you reuse any variables, at the least, you should state you're redefining them), it seems you're saying $a_n = \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{3}{2n(2n+3)}$, rather than $a_n$ being the $n$'th term of the original expression of $\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+3}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I fixed my soln

Comment: Thanks for taking care of this issue. Just forgetting to include $-b_n$ makes more sense than what I thought you'd likely done, i.e., redefined $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of real numbers that is bounded above (below) and is monotone increasing (decreasing) is convergent. The sum and difference of convergent sequences is of course convergent. However, I think it is easier to see here that
$$
\frac{1}{2n} - \frac1{2n+3} = \frac{3}{2n(2n+3)}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0.
$$